# How to create a folder directory structure in plaintext for documentation

Tags: git, directory

I need to document the directory structure of my node project. 
How can i create that like the image below in plain text
[image]

Comment: I cann't use window "tree" command as it will include node_modules folder as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows you can just write

```
tree > myfile.txt
```

Comment: I know that, but how can i exclude the node_modules folder

Comment: To exclude node_modules folder: `tree -I 'node_modules'`

Comment: Doesn't work for me on windows powershell. "Too many parameters - node_modules". Also: how do you exclude multiple folders? E.g.: ".sst", ".angular", "node_modules", ...